# Can update effect my code while updating project

Tags: jhipster

I am working on JHipster. I am working on the latest version: 0.8.3 and I have changed the project according to my requirements like change `Grunt.js`, `SecurityConfigure` Controller, Some `HTML` files.

But now I want to update the project with your upcoming version (0.9.0) by using command `Yo jhipster`.

I have a question in mind: if I update the project with your latest version, then will my changes be there or not? I.e. grunt file and SecurityConfigure and HTML file will be working fine for me or will I need to change them again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeoman will see you have modified your files, and it will ask you what to do: you can overwrite them, see a diff, etc...
I personally overwrite everything, and then use Git to see what has changed.

So a "normal" update shouldn't be an issue at all. For this next release, however, we have changed two things:

- Atmosphere is now optional, so if you don't choose this option, Yeoman will not be able to delete your previously generated files (you can't go wrong here, as your application won't compile if you keep the old files)
- The database data has changed (we added a new user), so Liquibase will complain if you already have some old data in your database (you also can't go wrong here, Liquibase will tell you about the issue)